# Internet Explorer won't display font icon using @font-face

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-awesome

I am having trouble getting a font to load properly in IE (IE9).  Works fine in Chrome.

You can see the issue by looking at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/Pn96Z/7/).  In IE9 a box is displayed, while in Chrome a star is displayed.

I am using the FontAwesome package found [here](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#).  I think the problem lies in the @font-face declaration at the top of the .css file (shown below).  Can someone see why IE wouldn't render this font?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svgz#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg'),
     url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the issue.  I had IE9 in compatibility mode.  When I turned that off, the font started to appear.

Comment: You can't imagine how much time took for me to figure out the same on an identical problem... took me like all day, good luck with your work

Answer (score 0):

In the jsfiddle, you are not setting `font-family` for any element, you are using italics (`i` element) but your `@font-face` specifies normal font only, and the jsfiddle does not demonstrate the issue because `@font-face` is missing (and would not work there, as the URLs are relative).

Moreover, your jsfiddle tries to style generated content, not normal content. The character used is a Private Use character (U+F060), and such characters are not supposed to be transmitted and used except by private agreements.

It is best to isolate the problem in the simplest case possible, to eliminate the effects of other issues (such as problems with generated content).

Comment: Ok.  I thought I had a simplest case in the Fiddle.  I am able to reproduce this locally (outside of the Fiddle environment), but since the CSS references font files, I had to add the FontAwesome package as  a resource for the Fiddle.  The resource on my server is unchanged from the original download from the FontAwesome website.  I believe if you look at the referenced css resource, you will see the font-family being set.  Also, since the font is pulling back in Chrome, I believe the relative URL is working.

Comment: I think it might be a missing setting on IIS and/or whatever web server jsFiddle uses.  I created a sample page and just loaded it from the filesystem into both browsers and it works fine.  I checked the MIME types in IIS, but .eot was already there and adding the others didn't solve the issue.